# Jquery.show() function is not working for divs inside an ASP Update Panel

Tags: jquery, updatepanel

I have an asp update panel and a div in it. But jquery show function is not working for this div. Is there any way to make it work ?

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#answerButton0").click(function() {
            $("#answerPanel0").show("slow");
        });

    });

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateQuestions" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="descHeader" style="width: 600px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Last 10 Questions"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="descContent" style="width: 600px; height: auto;">
                        <asp:Timer ID="timerPageLoad" runat="server" Interval="500" OnTick="timerPageLoad_Tick" />
                        <div id="loading" style="display: none; height: 60px;">
                            <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/site/process.gif" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="questionsPanelDiv" style="display: none;">
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlQuestions" runat="server">
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAsk" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

***#answerPanel0  and #answerButton0 are dynamically created from the code behind in pnlQuestions panel.***

Comment: Where exactly are #answerPanel0?

Comment: it seems, that answerPanel0 and answerButton0 won't be rendered correctly, nor both elements won't contain the corresponding id attrib value

Comment: its inside <asp:Panel ID="pnlQuestions"> ... here ... </asp:panel>

Comment: no when I see the page source after the page load I can see both divs with right IDs

Comment: then you have to do such `$(document).ready(function() {});` to give elements a chance to be loaded completely.

Comment: yes my script is just like that. But it is not working still :)

Comment: I would suggest doing this: `$(document).ready(function() {$("#answerButton0").on('click',function () {
            $("#answerPanel0").show("slow");
        });});` Thanks to mgraph.

Comment: Is the double period (`$("#answerButton0")..click(function() {`) a typo or in your actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#answerButton0').live('click', function () {
            $('#answerPanel0').show('slow');
        });
    });
```